# Loop error (List Index out of Range)

Tags: python-3.6

```
def clean_data(self):
    """Limit samples to greater than the sequence length and fewer
    than N frames. Also limit it to classes we want to use."""
    data_clean = []
    for item in self.data:
        if int(item[3]) >= self.seq_length and int(item[3]) <= self.max_frames \
                and item[1] in self.classes:
            data_clean.append(item)

    return data_clean
```

When I am trying to run this module it gives me the error of LIST INDEX OUT OF RANGE. Anyone, please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like some of your `data` items don't have the necessary length.

Answer (score 0):

`len(item) > 3` must be true  for each `item` in `self.data` or `item[3]` will fail with your reported error.  Check the length of your items and either fix them or add code to skip the `if` if the length is insufficient.